# Trying to compile an C app with MinGW: Not sure how to install libcurl

Tags: mingw, libcurl

So I am trying to compile this package https://github.com/Neisklar/quarkcoin-cpuminer and as per the instructions I have installed MinGW with MSYS. Now I just need to install libcurl so I can compile it, I have downloaded W64 devel version of cURL. But I don't know what to do with these files or if I have the right version of cURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar objective (to be able to compile CPUMiner on Windows 7 x64), and I successfully followed / came up with the instructions below.

http://pastebin.com/p2cRgHxd

They include both 64-bit and 32-bit targets.

See if they can help you out!